# Как из цикла получить нужные значения

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

Есть массив

`[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]...]`

Необходимо из него получить определенные срезы

Есть цикл:

```
x_size = 1280  
y_size = 720  
x_shift = 640  сдвиг по оси x
y_shift = 360  сдвиг по оси y
h = 1300  высота
w = 2100  ширина
for i in range(0, h, y_shift):
   print(f'{i}:{i+y_size}, {x_shift*2}:{i+x_size}')
```

Необходимо получить следующие значения

```
[0:720, 0:1280]
[360:1080, 640:1920]
[720:1440, 1280:2560]
[1080:1800, 1920:3200]
[1440:2160, 2560:3840]
```

Но пока что получаю такие

```
[0:720, 1280:1280]
[360:1080, 1280:1640]
[720:1440, 1280:2000]
[1080:1800, 1280:2360]
[1440:2160, 1280:2720]
```

Никак не могу разобраться как получить то что мне нужно

Comment: Ну блин, зачем было сегодняшний вопрос про срезы удалять, я почти ответ дописал

Comment: посчитала, что уже никто не ответит. удалила. а потом сама поняла как это сделать

Comment: Если в контексте этого вопроса смотреть, можно сразу не строки формировать, а объекты вида `(slice(a, b), slice(c, d))`, их можно в квадратных скобках подставлять, будет работать как вам нужно. Удаленный вопрос возможно восстановят голосованием, но это не точно) Надеюсь вы не против, если его вдруг восстановят)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не до конца понял что вам нужно, но вот это может вам помочь:

```
x_size = 1280
y_size = 720
x_shift = 640
y_shift = 360
h = 1300
w = 2100
for i in range(5):
    print(f'{i * y_shift}:{i * y_shift + y_size}, {i * x_shift}:{i * x_shift + x_size}')
```

Comment: добавила дополнение в условие

Comment: значения xstep, y_size, x_shift, y_shift вводятся пользователем, поэтому решение не должно быть привязано к константам.