# Как срез в виде строки преобразовать в объект, который можно использовать как срез массива

Tags: python, срез

В цикле получаю список срезов

```
qw = ['0:10, 0:20', '10:20, 20:40', '20:30, 40:60']
```

То есть каждый срез представлен в виде строки.
После этого пытаюсь применить этот срез к массиву

```
im = [[[0,0,0], [0,0,0]], [[0,0,0], [0,0,0]], [[0,0,0], [0,0,0]]...]
```

Но т.к. это строка, то применить не получиться.
Пыталась сделать так, но поняла что приду опять к строке

```
ind = i.split(',')
ind = [int(i) for i in ind]
int_ind = ','.join(ind)
```

Необходимо получить объекты массива по заданным срезам.

```
for i in qw:
  print(img[i])
```

где i должен быть работающим срезом, то есть

```
img[0:10, 0:20]
```

Comment: Правельно вопрсы задаем. Я из из этого (приводим пример), хочу получить вот это (приводим пример)

Comment: добавила больше описания

Comment: из qw что хотите получить? пример результата

Comment: добавила пример результата

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Нужно вытащить все числа из строк (это можно сделать с помощью регулярных выражений), преобразовать их в целые
2. Сформировать объект среза. Тут смысл в том, что срез вида `img[a:b]` - это объект типа `slice`, когда два среза через запятую - это кортеж (tuple) из двух `slice`. Т.е.:

   - `img[0:10]` это то же самое что `img[slice(0, 10)]` (или `img[slice(0, 10, None)]`, но пустой шаг слайса можно не указывать)
   - `img[0:10, 0:20]` - `img[(slice(0, 10), slice(0, 20))]`.

   В этом можно убедиться на таком коде:

   ```
   class Test:
       def __getitem__(self, x):
           return x


   print(Test()[0:10])  # slice(0, 10, None)
   print(Test()[0:10, 0:20])  # (slice(0, 10, None), slice(0, 20, None))
   ```

Таким образом, нужно сформировать объект вида `(slice(0, 10), slice(0, 20))`, подставить туда числа с первого шага.

```
import numpy as np
import re


def convert_to_slice(s: str):
    a, b, c, d = map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", s))  # Вытаскиваем все числа из строки (считаем, что их всегда 4 штуки)
    return (slice(a, b), slice(c, d))  # Формируем объект нужного вида


img = np.array([[[0,0,0], [1,1,1]], [[2,2,2], [3,3,3]], [[4,4,4], [5,5,5]]])

# Результат должен получиться одинаковым
print(img[0:1, 0:2])
print(img[convert_to_slice('0:1, 0:2')])
```

Результат:

```
[[[0 0 0]
  [1 1 1]]]
[[[0 0 0]
  [1 1 1]]]
```

---

Если смотреть в контексте вашего [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1401839/1365), то вместо формирования строк-срезов можно в цикле сразу формировать список из объектов-срезов:

```
def convert_to_slice(a, b, c, d):
    return (slice(a, b), slice(c, d))


qw = []

for i in range(5):
    qw.append(convert_to_slice(
        i * y_shift, i * y_shift + y_size,
        i * x_shift, i * x_shift + x_size,
    ))
```